# File handling is very slow

Tags: android, file-io

I am trying to read a file on my sdcard and stuff some additional info(very small though, like 20 bytes) and write the total info again to my sdcard. I am using FileInputStream and FileOutputStream to read and write the data. However, its is taking a long time to complete that operation. For ex., reading and writing a 100MB file is taking some 30 secs.

```
    File file = new File(globalSelectFile);
    byte[] b = new byte[20971520];       /Around 20MB

    FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(file);
    FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(new File(directory + "/"
            + actualFileName));
```

Is there a way to improve the performance?

Comment: where are those 20 bytes being written in the file: start of file, end of file, somewhere in the middle?

Comment: I'm surprised your application hasn't crashed. This `byte[] b = new byte[20971520];` allocation is too big for most phones where the available memory is only 16 MB. Why do you need such a big buffer?

Comment: @dmon  20mb is nothing for even the G1, the first android phone which had 192Mb of ram.  By2012, most have at least a gig, many have 2.

Comment: Except Android doesn't really give an application all of the available memory, not even close. 16 mb was the limit for the first devices.

Answer (score 1):

Sdcards are slow.  There is not much that can be done about that other than using a faster sd card ie a (class 2 card)

Aside from that, the only other option I know of is that you attempt to hide this latency from the user. Many Android devices are dual core now a days so I would suggest you 1, attempt to keep your reads and writes to a minimum and only do them when necessary, and 2, do them in a separate thread at times when the user is doing something else.  ie take in some input from the user, write it to disk while you take in some more.

Comment: Wow, a down vote for explaining that code can't change the laws of physics.  What is stackoverflow coming to?

Answer (score 0):

100MB is huge for a handheld device. And expect the kind of response times that you are getting with a device having limited resources as an Android phone.

Although it is not quite clear from the code snippet how you are using the 20MB byte array, but it can likely lead to a `OutOfMemoryError` if you are using byte arrays of that size. If you are using it as a buffer for copying the file, please try to reduce the size to much smaller value.